# Best practice to ensure member variable string is uppercase in c# (getter toUpper)

Tags: .net, string, performance, datamapper, getter-setter

So I wanted to pose this question to you guys, its a simple thing but i wanted to find a better way.

We have data that should always be uppercase but we allow lower case inputs that should be converted.

Normally we would just do a `toUpper` when we save to the DB.

I was thinking it might be better to `toUpper` in the getter, that way the logic is tighter to the data and as long as you use the Object to view this data then it will always be uppercase.

```
public string Mapping
{ 
    get
    {
        return mapping  == null ? mapping : mapping.ToUpper();
    }
    set;
}
```

Is this dumb? I know `Mapping.ToUpper()` will create a new string each time, so it seems dumb. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The above example would simply cause a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: I would not worry about the "cost" of creating a new string. The case conversion is a cheap operation and is only done a few times at most.

Answer (score 3):

I would convert the data on the way in, unless there is some compelling reason to keep the original data around. That way you ensure that you can't accidentally use the "bad" version of the data (for example, in a private method that accesses the backing field).

Personally I prefer that property setters always preserve the value, so that:

```
x.MyProperty = someValue;
Assert(x.MyProperty == someValue);
```

If the setter would change the value it is passed, I instead write a separate method to do it.

In your example, I'd probably go for:

```
public void SetMapUppercase(string value);
```

Comment: I like this. Thinking outside the property.